# Database scheme, autoincrement

Tags: sql-server

Database question here.
Is it possible to make an autoincrement on a secondary or a thirtiary ID?
I need to make something versionbased, so imagine this:

```
ID  Phrase  PhraseID    PhraseVersion
1   ""      1           1
2   ""      1           2
3   ""      1           3
4   ""      2           1
```

PhraseID can be the same number, when added to the database.
If the PhraseID exists, i want PhraseVersion to autoincrement in number.
If the PhraseID doesnt exist, i want PhraseVersion to start over, counting from 1.

I this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with a computed column for `PhraseVersion`, that will take the count of rows with the same `PhraseID` and `Id` lower or equal to the current row.

To do that, you need to create a UDF to calculate the PhraseVersion:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetPhraseVersion (
    @PhraseId int,
    @id int
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM T 
        WHERE PhraseId = @PhraseId 
        AND Id <= @id
    )
END
GO
```

Then, Create the table with the computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    PhraseId int,
    PhraseVersion as dbo.GetPhraseVersion(PhraseId, id)
)

GO
```

Now for the test - insert 4 records:

```
INSERT INTO T (PhraseId) VALUES(1),(1),(1),(2)
```

Select:

```
SELECT *
FROM T
```

Results:

```
id  PhraseId    PhraseVersion
1   1           1
2   1           2
3   1           3
4   2           1
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/LSKW45547)

Comment: Is this reliable on high frequency insertion? Is it possible to have duplicate PhraseId - PhraseVersion pairs?

Comment: I don't know. First I don't knoe what you consider high frequency and second I never tested it with big volumes of data. As tp your secpnd question,  that should not happen.

Comment: @ZoharPeled  It is taking to much time when apply filter on computed column.

Comment: @AGH I guess you are referring to using a computed column in the where clause. Unfortunately, since this column is based on a UDF it can't be marked as persisted and therefor can't be indexed. I don't know the specifics of your implementation so it's impossible for me to help further. You are always welcome to post a proper question if you have one.

Comment: @ZoharPeled this platform doesn't allow us duplicate question. I have same question and tried your answer commented my concern. However it's not your fault as questioner did not raise such requirement in his question.

Comment: A quick read of the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns?view=sql-server-2017) confirmed my previous comment - you can't index this column (but not because it's not persisted, because it's not deterministic). Perhaps there are other ways to achieve your goal (which I still don't know). Duplicate questions can be very often found in this platform - some gets closed as dupes before anyone can answer, some gets answers. It's worth a shot to ask, even giving a link to this post explaining why you want a different answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks for share reference document link.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished via an insert trigger on the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Phrases (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    PhraseID INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0), 
    PhraseVersion INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0))
GO

-- ==========================================================================================
-- Author:         Donna Landy
-- Create Date:    21 Nov 2019
-- Purpose:        To populate the PhraseVersion column (subordinate numeric key) on Insert
-- Note:           Must cater for >1 row being inserted when this trigger is called
-- Strategy:       Construct a temp table with the rows we need to consider, then update one row at a time
-- ==========================================================================================

CREATE TRIGGER Phrases_Insert ON Phrases AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ID INT
    DECLARE @PhraseID INT
    DECLARE @PhraseVersion INT

    DECLARE @i INT
    DECLARE @iMax INT

    -- Create and populate temp table
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#phrases', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #phrases
    CREATE TABLE #phrases (i INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, ID INT, PhraseID INT)
    INSERT INTO #phrases (ID, PhraseID) SELECT ID, PhraseID FROM inserted

    -- Scan temp table
    SET @i=1
    SELECT @iMax=MAX(i) FROM #phrases

    WHILE @i <= @iMax BEGIN

        -- Fetch PhraseID & PhraseVersion for the row we are going to update
        SELECT @ID=ID, @PhraseID=PhraseID FROM #phrases WHERE i=@i

        -- Find the highest current Ref
        SELECT @PhraseVersion=ISNULL(MAX(PhraseVersion),0) FROM Phrases WHERE PhraseID=@PhraseID

        -- Update the row 
        UPDATE Phrases SET PhraseVersion=@PhraseVersion+1 WHERE ID=@ID 

        -- Increment loop counter
        SET @i+=1

    END

    -- Remove temp table
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#phrases', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #phrases

END
GO
```