# In SQL Server how do I generate an auto-increment primary key ID that consists of year , a special char and a sequential series no.?

Tags: sql-server

I am encountering this kind of advance SQL coding task like generating an **auto-increment primary key ID that consists of a year, a special char and a sequential series no.**

Something like this.

```
2018-00000
2018-00001
```

so on and so forth...

I barely made this code

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STUDENT]
(
    [Stud_ID] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Stud_LName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Stud_FName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Stud_MName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
)
```

That will output like this

```
Stud_ID      Stud_LName   Stud_FName   Stud_MName  
--------------------------------------------------
2018-00000   Doe          Jane         Stack       
2018-00001   Doe          John         Stack
```

Comment: Please note It's highly recommended to use a standard `identity` column as your primary key, and since you need the year, unless you have a column that holds registration date from which you get that year, you will have to use the current year, meaning a computed column can't be persistent, meaning it can't be used as a primary key anyway.

Comment: @ZoharPeled thank for the responds but i don't have any registration date from which i get that year. Any alternative for this problem sir much appreciated if there is a code sample? and also i check the other similar post but i find it different on my post as what i think.

Comment: It's the same problem, and the same solution, only the details are somewhat different. You want a column that will be populated automatically by the database engine, but it's not a simple integer - the solution is to use a computed column.

Comment: ok sir i try to research about that computed column. thank for this i hope you don't if i add another comment when i don't find any solution?

Comment: Yeah, I don't mind. but if you want me to see it you should probably use `@` with my name: @zoharPeled.

Comment: @ZoharPeled sir. i found an alternative on my prob but there is a little problem in sequencing series of number. how should i filter this 2018-000010 into 2018-00010?

Here is the code that i found:
`CREATE TABLE seq
  (
     id   INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
     Emp_ID AS Concat(Year(Getdate()), '-', RIGHT(Concat('0000', id), 6)),
  name VARCHAR(10)
  ) `

Comment: This is a similar approach - using a computed column. However, please note that using identity values directly you might get gaps in your values.

Comment: @ZoharPeled sir what should i do to make this right? enlighten me please. i'm running out of idea. i hope you would share the tricks.

Comment: I've added an answer so that you could see exactly what I mean by same problem same solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete solution. Please note that it's exactly the same as the duplicate I've marked - [Database scheme, autoincrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277211/database-scheme-autoincrement) - Just different details.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STUDENT]
(
    [ID] int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Stud_LName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Stud_FName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Stud_MName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetSudentId
(
    @id int
)
RETURNS varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN Concat(Year(Getdate()), '-', RIGHT(Concat('0000', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STUDENT WHERE id < @Id)), 6))
END
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[STUDENT]
    ADD Stud_ID AS (dbo.GetSudentId(Id))
GO
```

Please note that the primary key of the table must still be the `identity` column (as shown in the script) since the computed column can't be the primary key.

Comment: I would rather have this marked as a duplicate since it really is one, but since I've reopened it I can't close it again. If this question doesn't get closed within the next few hours, and the solution in my answer actually did solve your problem, Please consider either voting to close yourself or accept this answer so that other people will know that the problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: This new column Stud_ID will never become a primary key using this method, because it is computed. Performance will be terrible when joining on the column or even selecting the column because of all the sub selecting. You also made a typo: **@id < @id**

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Of course you are correct about the primary key. I thought that the code was very obvious (since the identity column is marked as the primary key) I'll edit that explanation into my answer. Also, thanks for the catch about the typo!

Answer (score 0):

You should go through Computed column, which helps to manage your design. Please refer below example.

```
CREATE TABLE #test(id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
Stud_ID AS CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) as VARCHAR(4)) +'-'+ REPLICATE('0', 5 - DATALENGTH(CAST(id as VARCHAR(10))))+ CAST(id as VARCHAR(10)), 
Stud_LName VARCHAR(100), 
Stud_FName VARCHAR(100), 
Stud_MName VARCHAR(100)
)


INSERT INTO #test(Stud_LName, Stud_FName, Stud_MName)
values
('lname_1' , 'fname 1', 'mname 1'),
('lname_2' , 'fname 2', 'mname 2'),
('lname_3' , 'fname 3', 'mname 3'),
('lname_4' , 'fname 4', 'mname 4'),
('lname_5' , 'fname 5', 'mname 5'),
('lname_6' , 'fname 6', 'mname 6'),
('lname_7' , 'fname 7', 'mname 7'),
('lname_8' , 'fname 8', 'mname 8'),
('lname_9' , 'fname 9', 'mname 9'),
('lname_10', 'fname 10', 'mname 10')


select * from #test;


DROP TABLE #test;
```

Comment: Please note that identity columns might contain gaps in the values - `1, 2, 5, 6` and so on. that being said, This method should have much better performance than the one I've shown in my answer.

Comment: How identity column might contain gaps in the values? and How your query perform fast? can you please explain...!

Comment: When an insert fails, the identity number(s) that would be inserted are lost, and will not be assigned to new records. That leaves gaps. As the your second question, My answer would perform slower than yours, but will never have gaps. That's the trade off - either fast with potential gaps, or slow with no gaps.

Comment: Perfect, But that identity will get skipped in your example as well. so my concert is just that, we should go with identity column and computed column to avoid use of extra function.

Comment: Yes, the identity might have gaps but not the computed column. that's the only reason to use a udf in my answer.

Comment: I am agree with your efforts, but i dont see any advantages to use UDF. anyways thanks @ZoharPeled for this nice conversation.