# Auto alphanumeric Unique Id with C#

Tags: c#, alphanumeric

Total string length is 5 chars. I have a scenario, ID starts with: A0001 and ends with: A9999, B0001 to B9999

Now,

- If my product (a) will have A0001, A0002, etc....
- If my product (b) will have b0001, b0002, etc....

How to create this format?

I tried:

```
int a;
        using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("select * from voiceno WHERE ID = '1'", con))
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = command2.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                string val = dr["voiceno"].ToString();
                if (val == "0")
                {
                    txtinvoiceno.Text = "00001";
                }
                else
                {
                    a = Convert.ToInt32(dr["voiceno"].ToString());         
                    a = a + 1;
                    txtinvoiceno.Text = a.ToString("00000");
                }
            }

        }
```

**My table looks like**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[voiceno](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[voiceno] [nvarchar](50) NULL)
```

Comment: So, do you have a maximum of 26 lines, or would you then go on to have AA0001, AB0001, etc? sounds like you could add your line nr to the int of A in ascii (65) and then convert the output to char

Comment: no, I don't have a maximum @Icepickle can you explain to haw to do that

Comment: You want to save alphanumeric keys in your database like A00001... or you just want to show A00001 but actually in database it is 00001 ? If yes then what is the check to show "A" or "B" with the key.

Comment: But if your first product is A and your second is B, then it would imply that it goes till Z, which would be 26 lines, what happens after those 26 lines could be interesting

Comment: Something in your code doesn't seem quite right. You read the table _voiceno_ and get the value of _voiceno_ then you add 1 to this value and display it. Is this a way to find the maximum value present in your table and increment it to insert a new record?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the table schema for voiceno

Comment: yes, I want to save it like A00001 @ZainArshad how to show check it I don't know how to do that

Comment: Ahmed, you can do it like [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NA0moy)

Comment: @iakobski I update my question

Comment: @Icepickle look it will not be A and B it will be a name like (Zain, Ooredoo)

Comment: @Steve of course no I try this code to make the invoice

Comment: So it's the first letter of he name of the product, followed by 5 digits? Where do you get the product name for? Check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48486572/in-sql-server-how-do-i-generate-an-auto-increment-primary-key-id-that-consists-o) for a T-SQL solution to a similar problem

Comment: so you are saying that you primary keys will be something like "Zain00087", "John00987", "Boob67098"...? why in the world you would like your PKs like that ? Tell me what is your problem what you want to achieve may be I can suggest some better approach

Comment: every one of them has many invoices @ZainArshad and all of them in the same table. I want everyone to has something like Zain0001, Zain0002, etc....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a function that gets current value and gives you the next value:

```
public string Next(string cur)
{
    int num = int.Parse(cur.Substring(1));
    char chr = cur[0];
    num++;
    if (num > 9999)
    {
        num = 0;
        chr++;
    }
    return chr + num.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
}
```

To make it get last one from database:

You can get the current biggest ID from database like:

```
select Max(id) from voiceno
```

Also look at 
[Custom Auto-Generated Sequences with SQL Server](https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/custom-auto-generated-sequences-with-sql-server)

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WtlADR)

Comment: i don't get it, what do you mean by (Zian,Jon)

Comment: @ahmed_eltot93 this solutions is not saving the key to database, but you said you want to save them like this in database... Kindly be clear and precise with your question you are being very ambiguous

Comment: @ZainArshad yes I see that now I didn't try it and ask hem about what I see only , I'm with you

Comment: When using this approach how do you ensure two items don't try to write the same value back?  If thread A returns the current max value as 456 and before it writes the new value (presumable 457) back, thread B also returns 456?
PS: If you check the linked question you'll see entire responsibility is shifted to the DB to prevent that.

Comment: @MartinVenter if I want to create a new invoice to Zain it will be like Zain0001 if is VIVA it will be like VIVA0002, VIVA0003, etc....

Comment: So what happens if two Zains are issued?  You'd have the same race condition?

Comment: I don't think I'm explaining this clearly enough.  So if two Zains needs to be issued at the same time, the first Zain will ask the DB "what's the max number?" the database returns 0000 but before the first Zain has been saved (with 0001 as calculated in the code), the second Zain asks the database the same question, and 0000 will be returned again.

Comment: @ahmed_eltot93 you are not making any sense. Why Why Why just Why your are saving the like this ? There will be so much bugs after the system is deployed that you can't imagine. If there are two Zain and both are different people and have same name then what ? How would you know to whom this invoice belongs?

Comment: JUST DON"T DO THIS ! Tell me what you want why are you doing this I will suggest you a better approach.

Comment: I added a link to the answer, please have a look at it.

Comment: look@ZainArshad the Zian is a company ok and it has many invoices ok I want every invoice I will print to have a serial number like (Zian0001,.......) and in another company have the same like VIVA company have (Viva0001,.......)