# Generate Sequence for different entities

Tags: c#, sql-server

In our application , we have different items types , say A,B,C,D.

User can create an item for each of these types , and each item has to have it's own sequence number.

```
A-1 // the next item will have number as 2
B-2 // the next item will have number as 3
C-1
D-1
```

**Solution-1**

- I can create a separate table , storing the sequence number for each itemtype.
- Get the latest from this table , use it , increment that by 1 , and update this table
- This solution might lead to two items having the same number , if we don't implement any locking mechanism in the code.

**Solution -2**

- For each item type we define a sequence in DB
- Use next value for to get the next sequence number
- In this approach we don't have to do any locking mechanism in the code.

Please suggest what should be the approach to go forward , or is there any better way to achieve it.

Comment: Can you tolerate gaps in the numbers? I mean, if you have `A-1` and `A-3` but no `A-2`, is that a "deal breaker" for you, or as long as you have numbers in ascending order you'll be fine?

Comment: I'm not going to dupe-hammer your question just yet, but I think [the answer to this SO post is what you are looking for.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277211/database-scheme-autoincrement)

Comment: How should we know what those numbers mean for you? We can´t know what you consider "unique!, is it just the number or the number plus its type? Both are possible and valid. what fits you  scenario is only known to you. This is why I´m voting to close this question as opinion.based.

Comment: Can you guys not use the SQL table to handle the ID generation?  It would seem a lot simpler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I started with Solution-1, but I finally did go with Solution-2 to avoid dead-locks caused by the locks needed to prevent duplicates.

You can define a simple stored procedure to manage your custom sequences. It will create a new sequence when necessary, and return the next value of the correspondent sequence.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CUSTOM_SEQUENCES_NewValue]
    @TYPE nvarchar(32), 
    @VALUE int out
AS
  declare @SEQUENCE nvarchar(64); 
  declare @SQL nvarchar(128);
BEGIN
  set @SEQUENCE = N'SEQ_CUSTOM_SEQUENCE_' + @TYPE

  if not exists(select * from sys.sequences where name = @SEQUENCE) 
  begin
    set @SQL = N'create sequence dbo.' + @SEQUENCE + ' as bigint start with 1';
    execute sp_executesql @SQL;
  end

  set @SQL = N'set @VALUE = next value for dbo.' + @SEQUENCE;
  exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@VALUE int out', @VALUE = @VALUE out;
END
```

Comment: This is actually a nice solution. Please note, however, that if the potential gap between numbers for the same type is a problem, my proposed solution (in the link in the comment to the answer) is still better then this. Also, usually generating database objects should be a design time action, not a run time action. That being said, I think this answer still deserves a +1.

Answer (score 0):

If your item types does not extend then I would go with Solution-2, but if you expect this to grow then enhance Solution-1 with a CREATE TRIGGER ... FOR INSERT

Answer (score 0):

You said the answer already.  You have different item types so that's different tables for each A, B, C, and D.  Then each item has it's own ID, which is int for this case, and you get what you're looking for.